# Suggestions for a physics oriented book on Variational Calculus

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I would like to buy a good book on Variational Calculus. Most of the books that I find seem to be rather formal in a mathematical sense, which is not necessarily bad, but makes the studying a bit cumbersome.

Could you provide me with advice on a good variational calculus books which focuses on physics problems and has plenty of examples, preferably in the field of mechanics.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7737/2451

Comment: For a not-too-formal account of the calc of variations, [cornelius Lanczos' book](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Variational_Principles_of_Mechanics.html?id=ZWoYYr8wk2IC) is a good one